# sql coding to_date meaning

Tags: sql, sas

I have a sql code and couldn't understand the meaning

```
 proc sql; create table tito as 
 select distinct  j.perjobs_pidm,
     , to_date(to_char(t.pertito_time_entry_date,'YYYYMMDD')   ||t.pertito_time_in,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') tmi
                  from stg.pertito t
                     , stg.perjobs j

                 where t.pertito_jobs_seqno = j.perjobs_seqno
       ;quit;
```

the part I didn't understand is to_date part. How can I change this to SAS language. What is that code means? Thanks!

Comment: The crucial info not supplied for converting the code is whether STG is a SAS native library or a database library, subsequently which datatypes are columns pertito_time_entry_date and pertito_time_in.

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL equivalent of input(put(var,DATE9.)||':'||put(var2,TIME8.),DATETIME.), one way to combine date and time into datetime.  A superior SAS method would be

```
dtvar = dhms(datevar,0,0,timevar);
```

which uses the date for 'days' and the time for 'seconds' in the DHMS (days hours minutes seconds) function.

This works because a time variable is the number of seconds since midnight; so DHMS(date,0,0,time) creates a datetime variable.  IE, if it is 8am sharp, you could either do:

```
dhms(date,8,0,0) -> 8:00am on date
```

or

```
dhms(date,0,0,480) -> 8:00am on date
```

since 480 = 60*8.

Comment: I got the meaning but Confused with sas method dtvar = dhms(datevar,0,0,timevar); I will pick the variable tmi.

Comment: `dhms` is a function that creates a datetime variable out of day,hour,minute,seconds.  Since a time variable is # of seconds since midnight, you can use DHMS(datevar,0,0,timevar) to create a datetime.

Answer (score -1):

That code is taking two columns **pertito_time_entry_date** and **pertito_time_in**, and formatting then concatenating them in the code:

`to_char(t.pertito_time_entry_date,'YYYYMMDD')   ||t.pertito_time_in`

That whole block is then wrapped in to_date() which formats the entire expression to YYYYMMDDHH24MI.  This will then be stored as a date value that SAS can understand in the column **tito.tmi**.

Comment: I find this fairly difficult to understand as an explanation for what it's doing.  You're not at any point explaining what it actually is doing (combining a date and time).